# Adding images without coding them

Tags: java, android, xml

I found out,after decompiling apps like whatsapp,that they didnt refer to the images in neither the layout(xml) nor the java...the emojis exist in the drawable folder but in no like of code is the emoji refered to.for example if an emoji name was (happy_164) there is no line of code that contain that name.

So the question here is how do they do that?(how do they insert the emojis and other images without coding their names)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has clearly stated that they have violated the licensing terms of a proprietary application.

Comment: i'm really sorry if u thought that...i defined didn't intend to violate any copyrights. Whatsapp was just an apps i used as an example and i wanted to get to know how they do stuff like that.     I Apologize if u thought i did that, thx for understanded, just human curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use constants generated in the R class. They are numeric static constants. Java compiler/optimizer will replace them with the value as they go. There won't be a reference when decompiling.

Comment: So how do I know which image is for which numeric static?

Comment: You want to steal the content or just know how it works??

Comment: No of course not...im interested in knowing how they did it

Comment: Android sdk generates the R.java file. Java compiler substitutes constants by values. Third party developers do nothing about that. Java works like that. It only replaces basic types, though.

Comment: When i worked in j2me we used to remove the class with all the constants to save memory because it is useless after compiling.

Comment: Probably the constant is a hash or an index based on how or where resources get packed in the final binary.  Use a tool to find out https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/.  But the reason there's no reference is the one i said before

Comment: is there a way to know what these hex refer tom?alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

They just parse the folder. And they load any file found in this folder, if it had correct format for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a closer look into the style XML? Cause you only wrote about the layout XML.. There they can also refer to to the drawable.. It's just a hint.. I'm also interested solving this issue.. But logically, somehow, somewhere they need to refer..

Comment: I checked everywhere im pretty sure...but your right somewhere they must referr to it